# Variable not define newbie in Python

Tags: python

I made a menu to play a game in python. (Please See Below). However, I can t use my lists when I call setup_game or init_trigger. I tried to put them into the while and to also add a variable play so I can avoid the user to press 2 if he never played before. my issues are the following:

Why setup_game(possible_answers, female_charactere, male_charactere) or init_trigger(possible_answers, charactere_attributes) does not work if I put the list out of the while?

why is play not defined?

Please also give me feedback on the code itself, I am a newbie and I want to improve. Thank you!

```
### create the menu
def menu(): 
    print (30 * "-" , "MENU" , 30 * "-")
    print ("1. Replay")
    print ("2. Back to my first choice")
    print ("3. Exit")
    print (67 * "-")

## setup number of time player try the game
    play=0

## lists needed to run setup_game and init_trigger
 possible_answers= ["female","Female","F","girl","answer","Answer","a","yes","y","Yes","Y","kitchen","Kitchen","K","k","1","Leave","leave"] 
        female_charactere= ["boy","girl","he","his","him","prince"]
        male_charactere= ["girl","boy","she","her","her","princess"]

  
loop=True      
  
while loop:   ## While loop which will keep going until loop = False
    menu()    ## Displays menu
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice [1-3]: "))
     
    if choice==1:     
        print ("Your story is about to start")
        play=play+1      ##count number of time user play
        setup_game(possible_answers, female_charactere, male_charactere) ## launch game
        
    elif (choice==2 and play>=1):
        print ("Your are back to your first choice")
        play=play+1     ##count number of time user play
        init_trigger(possible_answers, charactere_attributes) ##lauch game at first choice
        
    elif (choice==2 and play==0):
        print ("You have not played yet, you are starting a new story")
        setup_game()
        
    elif choice==3:
        print("Thank you for playing!")
        loop=False # This will make the while loop to end as not value of loop is set to False
            
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing!")
        break
```

Comment: play is not defined because you have it limited to the scope of the function called `menu`. You may have done this accidently by indenting it

Comment: `play` is defined in the local function `menu`, not globally. You have not defined `init_trigger` and `setup_game `.

Answer (score 0):

> Why `setup_game(possible_answers, female_charactere, male_charactere)`
> or `init_trigger(possible_answers, charactere_attributes)` does not work
> if I put the list out of the while?

Here you're calling 2 functions you've yet to create. Unless you have more code that you did not share. Your app has no idea what to do with `start_game()` or `init_trigger()`.

> why is play not defined?

Python requires proper indentation, when you step into something like a function, loop, if statement, etc, you have to indent the code that belongs to it.

In your case, you've indented `play = 0` under the `menu()` function. Because of this, play only exists in the scope of `menu ()`. If you align `play = 0` left, that warning will disappear.